# Symbol scanner 'beep' on successful scan should be louder

Tags: barcode-scanner, motorola

I'm working with a motorolla MC75A which scans and beeps on a successful scan, I need to make the scanner Beep Louder.

Please let me know how to accomplish this !!!

I am currently managing 200 devices, Can i use some script to change it on all device at once.

Comment: Did you already found out, how to change this setting on one particular device? As by now that is not a programming question but a find-the-setting question.

Comment: Ya i did find out the way to change it for one device http://www.jargonsoft.com/support/knowledgebase.php?article=222 Still i wanted to know how to do it multiple devices